# How are 2-electron integrals usually computed?

Tags: molecular-modeling, ab-initio-calculations, integrals

I want to compute 2-electron coulomb integrals. When the Primitive Gaussian is not centered at 0, my quadrature scheme fails unless I increase the number of quadrature points. I am currently using a quadrature scheme for the 4-indexed integral:

- one integral involving the Boys function (1 coordinate)
- three integrals over  $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^3$

The integrals over the second coordinates $x_2$ are evaluated exactly at quadrature points.

Their respective numerical schemes are as follow:

- Gauss Chebyshev of the second type for one coordinate
- a tensor product of Gauss Chebyshev quadrature points for a 3D integration

My problem is that my integration over $\mathbb{R}^3$ scales pretty badly as I increase the number of quadrature points. So maybe using another scheme would be better, like Lebedev? Or are there other methods to simplify the 2-electron integrals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integral calculation is discussed extensively in the book [Molecular Electronic-Structure Theory by Helgaker, Jørgensen, and Olsen](https://doi.org/10.1002/9781119019572).

2-electron integrals are usually computed analytically with the [McMurchie-Davidson](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(78)90092-X) or [Obara-Saika](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.450106) methods and further developments thereof, or with [Rys quadrature](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.432807) which solves for the exact quadrature nodes and weights. Later on, [schemes based on approximate quadrature](https://doi.org/10.1080/00268976.2012.720725) have also been suggested.

You do not discuss what you are actually doing, but it seems you should first study the existing literature. I also point out that there exist efficient open source libraries for evaluating two-electron integrals, such as [LIBINT by Ed Valeev and collaborators](https://github.com/evaleev/libint), and [libcint by Qiming Sun](https://github.com/sunqm/libcint/).